# Post increment JAVA

Tags: java

what will be the output of the below code.

```
class x {
    psvm(){
        int j=0;
        for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
            j=j+1;
        sop(j); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand? That it outputs 101, or something else? What did you expect?

Comment: There are 101 iterations from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
```

This will do `i = 0` -> `i = 100`, which **101** iterations. If you want only 100 iterations exactly, you'd need either of these:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) // note: < only: 0 -> 99 = 100 iterations.
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) // note: change of starting point: 1 -> 100 = 100 iterations
```

---

comment followup:

This code:

```
j = j++;
```

is the functional equivalent of

```
temp = j;  // save current value of j, e.g 0 
j = j + 1; // increment j, e.g. j becomes 1
j = temp;  // put saved value into j, e.g. j goes back to 0
```

If you'd done:

```
j = ++j;
```

then it'd be

```
temp = j
temp = temp + 1
j = temp
```

or literally just

```
j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is `i<=100`. Your initial position is at 0. These two combine to give you 101 times around the loop.

Try `i<100`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
```

does exactly 101 iterations since you start with `0` and end with `100` (not before 100!)

Comment: You will end with 101, not 100 because you only exit the loop after teh condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: can u explain me more , temp=j;
j=j+1;
j=temp;

Answer (score 0):

You increment j by 1 and put the value to j:

```
i    j
0    1
1    2
....
100  101
```

I think it is pretty clear.

BTW is it your own initiative to write `j = j++` ? If you just want to exercise your trick skills, it is OK. But never use such technique is real code.

And take a look on code formatting conventions. Your code looks like almost obfuscated. It is very hard to read and understand it.

Comment: yeah ,but i want to know why it  is giving me the output 101 on my second code when i execute j=j+1;